# using id in assigned field

Tags: php, sql

I want to select the name, phone of a user where id is in an 'assigned' column,
I have this code but it displays nothing, please help

```
$sql = ("SELECT name, phone FROM users WHERE id IN (assigned)");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you expect this query to do.  Generally an `IN` clause would be a list of something, either manually defined or from an inner `SELECT` statement.  I would expect this to even perhaps be a syntax error.

Comment: happy to get a reply, seriously i know it's a syntax error, i only seek the correct syntax to use, i want to select the name and phone of the particular user in a table where the id is in another user's 'assigned' field.

Comment: Maybe you could provide sample data and sample output to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT  name, phone FROM users WHERE id IN (assigned)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. " - Phone: " . $row["phone"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want
 
`SELECT name, 
     phone 
FROM users 
WHERE [assigned] IN (id)`
 
but you have to know the user id that you want to pass through the query.

Let's say you have the users table:
 
`Assigned    Name        Phone
1           John Doe    202-555-1212
2           Mike Jones  281-330-8004
3           Xhaka       404-555-1842`

Then `SELECT name, 
     phone 
FROM users 
WHERE [assigned] IN (2)`

would produce the result:

> Mike Jones |  281-330-8004

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: i will manually input the user id into the assigned field, is the code you stated ok? will try it now

Comment: am getting '0 results'  on running the querry even when the id is still present in assigned field